# How to return a hyperlink to another worksheet based on a dropdown selection

Tags: excel, vba

My data sheet ("srData") is a pivot table that is filled using a userform. All data have a unique ID in column A of the data sheet. In the userform checkboxes are selected, which will change the cells, in columns K:AB, interior color to white(2), else interior color is grey(15) 
[image]
In my main worksheet ("Formulier"), based on the value of a drop down box (C6)where the unique ID is selected (i.e. SR-1, SR-2,SR-3 etc...), the headers from sheet("srData") are returned in column A of sheet("Formulier") starting from row 20 if the interior.colorindex=2. The values in the cells are returned in column D starting from row 20.
[image]
Now in Column Y and Z of ("srData") I have placed a hyperlink which links to a PDF.(see SR-4 first image) In column Y and Z there will allways be hyperlinks in the cells with interior.colorindex=2.

When I now select the unique ID from the dropdown on sheet("Formulier") I would like it to return an active hyperlink and not just tekst as it does now. Is this possible?
This is the code I have for returning the header and the values. The code was created by VBasic2008 so credit goes to him.
        `

```
Option Explicit
Public Const CriteriaCell As String = "C6"    ' Criteria Cell Range Address

Sub ColorSearch()

' Source
Const cSource As Variant = "srData"       ' Worksheet Name/Index
Const cCriteriaColumn As Variant = "A"    ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
Const cColumns As String = "K:AB"         ' Columns Range Address
Const cHeaderRow As Long = 1              ' Header Row Number
Const cColorIndex As Long = 2             ' Criteria Color Index (2-White)
' Target
Const cTarget As Variant = "Formulier"    ' Worksheet Name/Index
Const cFr As Long = 20                    ' First Row Number
Const cCol As Variant = "A"               ' Column Letter/Number
Const cColVal As Variant = "D"            ' Value Column Letter/Number

Dim Rng As Range      ' Source Found Cell Range
Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
Dim vntC As Variant   ' Color Array
Dim vntV As Variant   ' Value Array
Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
Dim vntTV As Variant  ' Target Value Array
Dim i As Long         ' Source/Color Array Column Counter
Dim k As Long         ' Target Array Row Counter
Dim sRow As Long      ' Color Row
Dim SVal As String    ' Search Value
Dim Noe As Long       ' Source Number of Elements

' Write value from Criteria Cell Range to Search Value.
SVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(CriteriaCell)

' In Source Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
    ' Search for Search Value in Source Criteria Column and create
    ' a reference to Source Found Cell Range.
    Set Rng = .Columns(cCriteriaColumn) _
            .Find(SVal, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
    ' Check if Search Value not found. Exit if.
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Write row of Source Found Cell Range to Color Row.
    sRow = Rng.Row
    ' Release rng variable (not needed anymore).
    Set Rng = Nothing
    ' In Source Columns
    With .Columns(cColumns)
        ' Copy Header Range to Header Array.
        vntH = .Rows(cHeaderRow)
        ' Copy Color Range to Color Array.
        vntC = .Rows(sRow)
        ' *** Copy Color Range to Value Array.
        ' Note: The values are also written to Color Array, but are
        '       later overwritten with the Color Indexes.
        vntV = .Rows(sRow)
        ' Write number of columns in Source Columns to Source Number
        ' of Elements.
        Noe = .Columns.Count
        ' Loop through columns of Color Range/Array.
        For i = 1 To Noe
            ' Write current ColorIndex of Color Range to current
            ' element in Color Array.
            vntC(1, i) = .Cells(sRow, i).Interior.ColorIndex
        Next
    End With
End With
' Resize Target Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
ReDim vntT(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)
' *** Resize Target Value Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
ReDim vntTV(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)
' Loop through columns of Color Array.
For i = 1 To Noe
    ' Check if current value in Color Array is equal to Criteria
    ' Column Index.
    If vntC(1, i) = cColorIndex Then
        ' Count row in Target Array.
        k = k + 1
        ' Write value of current COLUMN in Header Array to
        ' element in current ROW of Target Array.
        vntT(k, 1) = vntH(1, i)
        ' *** Write value of current COLUMN in Value Array to
        ' element in current ROW of Target Value Array.
        vntTV(k, 1) = vntV(1, i)
    End If
Next

' Erase Header and Color Arrays (not needed anymore).
Erase vntH
Erase vntC
Erase vntV '***

' In Target Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
    ' Calculate Target Range by resizing the cell at the intersection of
    ' Target First Row and Target Column, by Number of Elements.
    ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
    .Cells(cFr, cCol).Resize(Noe) = vntT
    ' *** Calculate Target Value Range by resizing the cell at the
    ' intersection of Target First Row and Value Column, by Number of
    ' Elements.
    ' Copy Target Value Array to Target Value Range.
    .Cells(cFr, cColVal).Resize(Noe) = vntTV
End With

End Sub
```

`

Comment: Y and C 5 are formulas?

Comment: In Y5 and Z5 there is a hyperlink. The hyperlink is of a PDF file. No formula in these cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a backup before and give this a try:

```
Option Explicit
Public Const CriteriaCell As String = "C6"    ' Criteria Cell Range Address

Sub ColorSearch()

' Source
Const cSource As Variant = "srData"       ' Worksheet Name/Index
Const cCriteriaColumn As Variant = "A"    ' Criteria Column Letter/Number
Const cColumns As String = "K:AB"         ' Columns Range Address
Const cHeaderRow As Long = 1              ' Header Row Number
Const cColorIndex As Long = 2             ' Criteria Color Index (2-White)
' Target
Const cTarget As Variant = "Formulier"    ' Worksheet Name/Index
Const cFr As Long = 20                    ' First Row Number
Const cCol As Variant = "A"               ' Column Letter/Number
Const cColVal As Variant = "D"            ' Value Column Letter/Number

Dim Rng As Range      ' Source Found Cell Range

Dim targetCell As Range ' Cell to add hyperlink

Dim vntH As Variant   ' Header Array
Dim vntC As Variant   ' Color Array
Dim vntV As Variant   ' Value Array
Dim vntHy As Variant   ' Hyperlink Array (*)
Dim vntT As Variant   ' Target Array
Dim vntTV As Variant  ' Target Value Array
Dim vntTH As Variant    ' Target Hyperlink
Dim i As Long         ' Source/Color Array Column Counter
Dim k As Long         ' Target Array Row Counter
Dim sRow As Long      ' Color Row
Dim SVal As String    ' Search Value
Dim Noe As Long       ' Source Number of Elements

Dim hyperlinkCounter As Long     ' Counter for assigning hyperlink

' Write value from Criteria Cell Range to Search Value.
SVal = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Range(CriteriaCell)

' In Source Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cSource)
    ' Search for Search Value in Source Criteria Column and create
    ' a reference to Source Found Cell Range.
    Set Rng = .Columns(cCriteriaColumn) _
            .Find(SVal, , xlValues, xlWhole, , xlNext)
    ' Check if Search Value not found. Exit if.
    If Rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    ' Write row of Source Found Cell Range to Color Row.
    sRow = Rng.Row
    ' Release rng variable (not needed anymore).
    Set Rng = Nothing
    ' In Source Columns
    With .Columns(cColumns)
        ' Copy Header Range to Header Array.
        vntH = .Rows(cHeaderRow)
        ' Copy Color Range to Color Array.
        vntC = .Rows(sRow)
        ' *** Copy Color Range to Value Array.
        ' Note: The values are also written to Color Array, but are
        '       later overwritten with the Color Indexes.
        vntV = .Rows(sRow)
        ' Write number of columns in Source Columns to Source Number
        ' of Elements.
        Noe = .Columns.Count

        ' Redimension
        ReDim vntHy(1 To 1, 1 To Noe)

        ' Loop through columns of Color Range/Array.
        For i = 1 To Noe
            ' Write current ColorIndex of Color Range to current
            ' element in Color Array.
            vntC(1, i) = .Cells(sRow, i).Interior.ColorIndex
            If .Cells(sRow, i).Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then

                vntHy(1, i) = .Cells(sRow, i).Hyperlinks(1).Address
            End If
        Next
    End With
End With
' Resize Target Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
ReDim vntT(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)
' *** Resize Target Value Array to Number of Elements rows and one column.
ReDim vntTV(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)

' Resize target hyperlink array
ReDim vntTH(1 To Noe, 1 To 1)



' Loop through columns of Color Array.
For i = 1 To Noe
    ' Check if current value in Color Array is equal to Criteria
    ' Column Index.
    If vntC(1, i) = cColorIndex Then
        ' Count row in Target Array.
        k = k + 1
        ' Write value of current COLUMN in Header Array to
        ' element in current ROW of Target Array.
        vntT(k, 1) = vntH(1, i)
        ' *** Write value of current COLUMN in Value Array to
        ' element in current ROW of Target Value Array.
        vntTV(k, 1) = vntV(1, i)

        ' Add hyperlink to array
        vntTH(k, 1) = vntHy(1, i)

    End If
Next

' Erase Header and Color Arrays (not needed anymore).
Erase vntH
Erase vntC
Erase vntV '***

' In Target Worksheet
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget)
    ' Calculate Target Range by resizing the cell at the intersection of
    ' Target First Row and Target Column, by Number of Elements.
    ' Copy Target Array to Target Range.
    .Cells(cFr, cCol).Resize(Noe) = vntT
    ' *** Calculate Target Value Range by resizing the cell at the
    ' intersection of Target First Row and Value Column, by Number of
    ' Elements.
    ' Copy Target Value Array to Target Value Range.
    .Cells(cFr, cColVal).Resize(Noe) = vntTV

    ' Assign hyperlinks to cells
    For Each targetCell In .Cells(cFr, cColVal).Resize(Noe)

        ' Remove previous hyperlinks
        If targetCell.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then

            targetCell.Hyperlinks.Item(1).Delete

        End If

        ' Add new hyperlink
        If vntTH(hyperlinkCounter + 1, 1) <> vbNullString Then

            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(cTarget).Hyperlinks.Add targetCell, vntTH(hyperlinkCounter + 1, 1)

        End If



        hyperlinkCounter = hyperlinkCounter + 1
    Next targetCell

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I have one question. In my sheet("Formulier") if I select the SR-4 in the dropdown it correctly displays the hyperlink in cells D21 and D22. But when I then select one of the other unique ID's the values in D21 and 22 look like a hyperlink (blue and underlined). They are not hyperlinks though. In my private sub worksheet_change I have the folowing code: Range("A20:E28,G20:H37,J20:K32").ClearContents but this doesn't remove the blue color or under line). Is there a way to do this without losing the format. The cells are combined. Don't want to lose this.

Comment: I Updated the code to remove previous hyperlink. Please mark the answer if it helped you

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the way you can turn a string to a Hyperlink is the following:

```
Sub text2Hyperlink()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim URL As String
    Dim filePath As String
    Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Worksheet Name") ' whichever worksheet you're working with
    filePath = ".....\Something.pdf"
    URL = "https://www.google.com/"
    sht.Hyperlinks.Add sht.Range("A1"), filePath
    sht.Hyperlinks.Add sht.Range("A2"), URL
End Sub
```

This takes some text stored in a string, and assigns it as a hyperlink in a cell. It works both for websites and files

In this case you end up with a link to a file in cell A1 and with a link to a webpage in cell A2.
You can modify this to suit your needs.